# Port 60h Release key assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am writing code to read directly from port 60h but without defining interrupt. It is just a function. However, When I press down key for example after releasing the up key, It doesn't read the down key properly or It seems to be reading the previous key instead,
msg1,2,3,4 are for testing.

```
mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h
     mov cx,32
    ll: 
        mov al,0
        in al,60h
        mov dl,al
        and al,80h
        cmp al,80h
        je ll
        cmp dl,48h
        jne try2
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        jmp print 
        try2:
        cmp dl,50h
        jne try3
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        jmp print2 
        try3:
        cmp dl,4Dh
        jne try4
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        jmp print3
        try4:
        cmp dl,4Bh
        jne ll
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        jmp print4 
        loop ll
    jmp d
    print: mov dx,offset msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp ll
    print2: mov dx,offset msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp ll
    print3: mov dx,offset msg3
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp ll
    print4: mov dx,offset msg4
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp ll
    d:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are interrupts enabled? If yes, default IRQ1 handler also interacts with keyboard controller and you got race.